# Add XML node where element value equal n

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have a XML file which looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Orders>
  <Order>
    <OrderNumber>123</OrderNumber>
    <ClientName>Name</ClientName>
    <TotalOrderCost>50</TotalOrderCost>
    <Products>
      <Product>
        <Name>Games</Name>
        <Quantity>3</Quantity>
        <Price>10</Price>
        <TotalProductPrice>30</TotalProductPrice>
      </Product>
      <Product>
        <Name>CDs</Name>
        <Quantity>2</Quantity>
        <Price>10</Price>
        <TotalProductPrice>10</TotalProductPrice>
      </Product>      
    </Products>
  </Order>
  <Order>
    <OrderNumber>456</OrderNumber>
    <ClientName>Name 2</ClientName>
    <TotalOrderPrice>15</TotalOrderPrice>
    <Products>
      <Product>
        <Name>Tea</Name>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        <Price>15</Price>
        <TotalProductPrice>15</TotalProductPrice>
      </Product>
    </Products>
  </Order>
</Orders>
```

I have a form where the user selects an order and can add more products in it. I can output the correct XElement which looks like:

```
      <Product>
        <Name>Coffee</Name>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        <Price>15</Price>
        <TotalProductPrice>15</TotalProductPrice>
      </Product>
```

How do I add this XElement under the products of an order user has selected? So if the user selects OrderNumer = 456 and adds the product using the form, the XElement goes under 456 order.

I have tried:

```
xmldoc2.Element("Orders").Element("Order").Element("Products").Add(addProduct);
xmldoc2.Save(orderFilePath);
```

which always adds the product to the first order on the XML and I can see the reason for it however I cannot see how I could add under the product under the  order selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should select order element to which you want to add new product:

```
int number = 456;
var order = xmldoc2.Element("Orders").Element("Order")
                   .FirstOrDefault(o => (int)o.Element("OrderNumber") == number);

// check if order not null    
order.Element("Products").Add(addProduct);
```

You also can use XPath for selecting order:

```
var xpath = String.Format("//Order[OrderNumber[text()={0}]]", number);
var order = xmldoc2.XPathSelectElement(xpath);
```

Comment: does my xmldoc2 has to be XmlDocument or XDocument?

Comment: @YagneshCangi it should be `XDocument` as it is now

Comment: I  have tried the first solution and intellisense is not bringing  FirstOrDefault

Comment: XPath is working and I can get the correct Order xml of 456. How do i save that in the current XML I have?

Comment: Just had to xmldoc2.Save(filepath).  Thank you soo much for you help.

Comment: @YagneshCangi `FirstOrDefault` is an extension from `System.Linq` namespace. `XPathSelectElement` is an extension from `System.Xml.Xpath` namespace. And I see that you already found how to save xml file